# How to find the line when sentry report an error?

Tags: sentry, react-native-sentry

I have difficulties to fix my errors because i can't find the correct line where my bug is located.

```
 app:///%40user%2Fmyapp- 
 vb7dxozbb0%2F1.0.1%2F6f8d9d7dc229b282bf44ec44d68caa41-25.0.0-ios.js in 
 exports at line 1238:97
```

any idea ?

Comment: I'm not an expert on this topic, but it seems like you would want to set up sourcemaps: https://docs.sentry.io/clients/javascript/sourcemaps/

Comment: Oh thanks. this is exactly what i needed to know. Thanks again.